# How to resolve Cannot import module '@nuxt/builder'?

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, nuxt.js

So I recently created a new project at home using .NET Core with a Nuxt.js front-end.

I know the site ran when it was just a Vue app. I know the site ran when it was a base Nuxt.js app after following [this post](https://samwalpole.com/how-to-run-nuxt-from-a-aspnet-core-web-application).

Then I wanted to add some features we use on the Nuxt project I inherited at work but I'm running into this error when I try to build it.

```
 FATAL  Cannot import module '@nuxt/builder'                                                                                                  16:16:47  

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
  at n (node_modules\jiti\dist\v8cache.js:2:2472)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\utils\setupHooks.js:8:39)
  at Module.o._compile (node_modules\jiti\dist\v8cache.js:2:2778)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
```

I can see that @nuxt/builder is referenced in my package-lock.json file at work, but it is not referenced in the package.json file.

I tried installing the 'missing' package in my home project yet the error remains.

It feels like - from what I've read - that this package is built into Nuxt in some fashion, but that Nuxt has lost it's marbles and isn't finding it.

What can I do to fix this as there are no examples I can find through searching that covers this specific failure, so I'm blocked and don't know how to move forward. I'd prefer not to start all over again, plus I'm keen to understand the root cause.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting... as a hunch I added a reference to @nuxt/builder in the buildModules section in nuxt.config.js and low n behold, the issue is resolved. Of course, there are now two more problems but such is development life. Now it's complaining that Webpack is missing, yet we don't reference either of these packages in our package.json at work - so that suggests to me that we have configured these packages elsewhere for a build process that is defined outside the immediate project files. Hmmmm.

Comment: Nuxt depends on Webpack under the hood (as does Vue CLI's build process). `webpack` is a transitive dependency here, and it wouldn't be listed in your `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks @tony19, that's what I suspected. Turns out it was a 'red herring'. I stripped back my Nuxt config and enabled features one by one and resolved other issues until I now have a working project. I think it was a case of just throwing too many things in at once and hoping it would just all play together nicely. Should know these things by now :P

Comment: In my case I used NPM (package-lock.json) and yarn (yarn.lock.json). I removed one and reinstall the packages.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I removed package-lock.json and node_modules, then re-run

> npm install
>
> npm run build

Answer (score 0):

For those in the same boat as I was, think critically.

If something feels wrong it probably is. Revert your changes if possible until your project works again, then be sure to test each addition/change as they're made.

In my case I turned a bunch of settings off and removed packages that were ultimately not needed (i.e. webpack and @nuxt/builder as they're a part of Nuxt as I suspected) then followed the steps above until things started working again.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, so what did you exactly do in terms of reversing stuff? I didn't really remove anything that could cause the issue and I have the same issue as you did but still I am not able to figure out what is up.

Comment: Hi @Robert - It's been a bit too long for me to remember the details now but I think it would have been a case of removing the packages I'd added since the project last worked, and reversing any configuration changes i'd made e.g. in nuxt.config.js, and then just get the project building. Then start adding things again one by one. I think the key problem was making too many changes at once and not understanding what was actually trying to use Webpack, and probably not clearing node_modules and re-installing packages fully after some changes too.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for replying! No worries. I found another solution. I have set up a brand new installation of the NuxtJS framework and moved my existing code over there, cleaned up stuff a bit at the same time and it all works now! Took me maybe an hour so I am glad I didn't waste days on fixing that! :)

Comment: Yep that's another way of doing it @Robert, I may be doing the same thing myself on an upcoming project.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this error for an hour. The stack trace was:

```
 ERROR  Cannot import module '@nuxt/builder'                                                                                  15:17:39

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
  at n (node_modules/jiti/dist/v8cache.js:2:2472)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js:4:26)
  at Module.o._compile (node_modules/jiti/dist/v8cache.js:2:2778)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
```

I looked into `node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js` and on L4 I saw this:

```
const RequestShortener = require('webpack/lib/RequestShortener')
```

On a hunch I ran `npm ls webpack` and saw an unmet peer dependency. I then ran `npm install --save-dev webpack` and the error was fixed.